# Is it possible to check if a variable is located at L1/L2/L3 cache

Tags: c++, c, caching, profiling, memory-address

As all we know, in a modern architecture of computer, there are L1/L2/L3 cache, which can improve the performance of execution of a program.

My question is if we can know if a variable is loaded into L1/L2/L3 cache while executing?

We know that we could print the address of a variable in C++ like this: `int i; cout << &i;`. So if the `i` is loaded into the L1 cache, which kind of address is shown by the `&i`? the address of L1 cache or the address of the RAM?

Comment: It will show the address of `i` on the stack, so the RAM. I am pretty sure that checking if stuff is in the cache while executing will more likely slow the code down^^.

Comment: You can't know, at least in portable C++ since the address of an object never changes.  Instead of worrying about it, what you should do is make sure that your variables are "hot" so they are more likely to be in the cache.

Comment: You can use hardware performance counters, e.g., via PAPI library, to check whether a cache hit or miss occurs when accessing some memory location.

Comment: You'll have to look at the data sheet for the processor and maybe also your platform.  In many systems, the L1 & L2 caches are not accessible outside the processor.

Comment: It doesn't matter the slightest where the variable ends up _because you write to screen using numerous system calls, graphics memory etc etc_. Calling `cout` takes approximately 99.999% of all execution time of this program, and you worry about the performance of the remaining 0.001%.

Comment: What about variables that are located in registers?  In general, registers may be faster than L1/L2/L3 cache.  Registers don't have addresses.  If you take the address of a variable, it can't be in a register anymore (because registers don't have addresses).

Comment: @Lundin:  Pardon my naivete, but where in the post is writing to the screen mentioned?  Did I miss something?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews cout is an ostream object directed to stdout.

Comment: @Lundin I still don't see where the screen is mentioned.  The `stdout` may be connected to a terminal, or routed to a file (all at the operating's systems discretion).  Also, the `cout` is an example of using a variable's address.  There is no mention of platform, so the OP may be running on an embedded system that doesn't have a screen.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  `void func(int i) { cout << &i; }` If registers don't have addresses, so what does this code tell me?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews And how exactly is writing to a serial terminal or file _faster_ than writing to the screen? Or are you making remarks just for the sake of it?

Comment: @Yves The variable is not placed into a register, but in memory.   Your function is printing the variable's location in memory (either stack or something similar).  By definition, a variable whose address is taken must reside in addressable memory.  So the compiler will change the location of the variable.   Look at the assembly language.

Comment: @Lundin:  I'm saying you are adding stuff to the OP's question that isn't there.  Fundamentally, the OP wants to know how to get the address of a variable in cache.  The profiling tag may be added because the OP wants to know the efficiency of accessing the cache.  We don't know the purpose of the OP's questions.  You can't assume that the OP is writing to a screen or graphics memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can bloody well assume that they are either writing to a screen (slow), or to a file (slower) or to a serial terminal (slowest). If they aren't interested in benchmarking `cout` but rather variable access, we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typical PC, `&i` is always the address of a RAM location. This is because the cache is essentially transparent to the programmer. It simply stores a copy of the same information contained in a region of memory, at a place that can be more quickly accessed by the CPU. It is not addressable as a memory location directly.

As for whether the variable is 'located' in the cache while the code is executing, it most certainly is. When you try to access data in a memory location, if it is not already in the cache, it will be brought into the cache first before your request is served.